# If one has an aim of being a good programmer, what should one prefer, contributing to open source projects or solving codechef.com problems?

Tags: open-source

I am a college student keen to improve my Programming skills. I have two pathways to follow:

1. Contributing to OpenSource Projects
2. Solving puzzles at codechef.com

Which one should I follow?

Comment: By 'Good' I mean , a programmer who can solve even the toughest problems and still has knowledge of how projects are created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good programmer is one who cares about his or her ACE - *Accuracy*, *Clarity*, *Effectiveness*.

- A good programmer cares about the **Accuracy of code**. The easy part is coding the "happy path" because this is always in the forefront of our minds when we design and write the code. But what about potential the exception paths that exist when presented with unexpected input and edge case behaviours of the chosen implementation provided? Care is shown by taking the time to think through all the code paths, investing time in testing, submitting the code for peer review, and having the willingness to accept other's suggestions and make changes when appropriate.
- A good programmer cares about the **Clarity of code**. Whether the code is well structured, expressive, adheres to the Open-Closed Principle, the Single Responsibility Principle, the executing machine doesn't care one bit. But, these are all very important to the next programmer, or yourself, who has to read and understand your code at a later date in order to fix bugs, modify behaviours, or add features.
- A good programmer cares about the **Effectiveness of code**. Does it satisfy all the constraints imposed on it? Not only performance and space constraints, but also aspects that make it acceptable to the end user, the demands on the development and testing timelines by your clients, boss, family. Professional software development is not a precise circumscribed task, like "calculate the determinant of an NxN matrix". It has many constraints and demands, and good programmers are mindful of all of these, and will do their best to manage the them, especially when there is not enough time to satisfy all constraints completely.

So! To answer your immediate question, Open Source or codechef, I'd say that being involved in an Open Source project provides much greater opportunities to practice being a good software developer. So go choose an Open Source project that you care about, and ACE it!

Comment: What does `ACE` stand for?